# Selenium grid. параллельный запуск тестов в python

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest, selenium-grid

Сейчас я использую такую конструкцию для запуска тестов. Я передаю в команднйо строке имя браузера и количество потоков припомощи `pytest-xdist`

```
def __init__(self, browser):
    desired_capabilites = None
    comand_executor = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"

    if browser == "chrome":
        desired_capabilites =  {
                "browserName": "chrome",
                "maxInstances": 5
            }
    elif browser == "firefox":
        desired_capabilites = {
            "browserName": "firefox",
            "maxInstances": 5
        }

    self.driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor=comand_executor,
        desired_capabilities=desired_capabilites)
```

Но этот способ, как мне кажется, имеет несколько недостатков:

- Перед запуском всегда нужно запускать *selenium-server* (`java -jar selenium-standalone-server.jar`)
- Что бы протестировать всё в разных браузерах - мне приходится
  запускать       тесты дважды (один раз для chrome, второй для ff)

Можно ли как-то автоматизирвоать запуск сервера?

И как запустить тесты параллельно в разныых браузерах?

Отличным вариантом было бы создавать две ноды и запускать тесты одновременно в обоих. Или же создавать в одной ноде несколько различных браузеров и запускать уже в них. Но я не знаю как. Заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: посмотрите в сторону Selenoid https://aerokube.com/selenoid/latest/